# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInfo') at index2.js:20:20

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, javascript

i am going to call a smart contract method in web.js ( i am using legacy web.js)

my solidity code as follow :

```
pragma solidity 0.5.4;

contract Register {
    string private info;

    function setInfo(string memory _info) public {
        info = _info;
    }

    function getInfo() public view returns (string memory) {
        return info;
    }
}
```

my javascript code also as follow:

```
var contractAddress = '0xD92C7Ee99C936E5CAECa032CB0212d76b7276CA9';
var abi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getInfo","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_info","type":"string"}],"name":"setInfo","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]');
window.onload = async function () {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        console.log("This is DAppp Environment");
        var accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        var currentAddress = accounts[0];
        console.log(currentAddress)
        web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        mycontract = new web3.eth.contract(abi, contractAddress); // add your alreay defined abi and address in Contract(abi, address)
        console.log(mycontract);

    } else {
        console.log("Please connect with metamask");
    }
    
}
mycontract = new web3.eth.contract(abi, contractAddress);
mycontract.methods.getInfo().call().then((res) => {
    alert(res);
}).catch((err) => {
    alert(err);
})
```

and the output of my code in browser is :
[image]

how can i solve this error and get data from my contract as you know i am going to **call getInfo method from javascript by using web.js (legacy web.js)**

thanks in advance

Comment: What web3 version are you using? It appear you are using an old version. In that case try upgrading to a more recent one.

Answer (score 0):

The `contract` property you are refering to does not exists. But `Contract` does (capital c).

So change this:

```
mycontract = new web3.eth.contract(abi, contractAddress);
```

to:

```
mycontract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
```